# Brunch with SugarSS (PostCSS parser)

Tags: brunch, postcss

How can I start using [SugarSS parser](https://github.com/postcss/sugarss) with Brunch?

Here is the `plugins` part of my current config:

```
exports.config = {

  ...

  plugins: {
    babel: {
      ignore: [/web\/static\/vendor/]
    },
    postcss: {
      processors: [
        require("postcss-cssnext")(["last 3 versions"]),
        require("precss"),
        require("lost")
      ]
    },
    cssnano: {
      autoprefixer: {
        add: false
      }
    }
  }

  ...

};
```

And my `package.json`:

```
{
  "repository": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-brunch": "~6.0.0",
    "brunch": "~2.1.3",
    "css-brunch": "~1.7.0",
    "cssnano": "^3.5.2",
    "cssnano-brunch": "^1.1.5",
    "javascript-brunch": "~1.8.0",
    "lost": "^6.7.2",
    "phoenix": "file:deps/phoenix",
    "phoenix_html": "file:deps/phoenix_html",
    "postcss-brunch": "^0.5.0",
    "postcss-cssnext": "^2.5.1",
    "postcss-scss": "^0.1.7",
    "precss": "^1.4.0",
    "sugarss": "^0.1.2",
    "uglify-js-brunch": "~1.7.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way PostCSS plugin for brunch works is, it's invoked after all the stylesheets were compiled and concatenated into a single file. (Brunch calls that an *optimizer* plugin)

Support of SugarSS or similar, however, will require creating of a custom *compiler* plugin, that will only transform sss into normal css.

It's actually easier than it sounds :) Use [plugins.md](https://github.com/brunch/brunch/blob/master/docs/plugins.md) as a plugin API reference. If it helps, take a look at `stylus-brunch` — https://github.com/brunch/stylus-brunch/blob/master/index.js.

What you'll basically need to change is:

1. `compile()` method, to invoke PostCSS with SugarSS parser and return a promise that resolves to an object with at least the `data` key (which in your case will be a string css)
2. change `prototype.extension` to be the extension you want to handle, `sss` in this case
3. you probably won't need stylus' `constructor()` and might not need the css modules support
4. you can release it so that other people looking to use SugarSS with Brunch won't have do this themselves. Sharing is caring, right? :)

   (If you do go that route, it's customary to name brunch plugins with a suffix, like `sugarss-brunch`. You can also then include it in our list of plugins https://github.com/brunch/brunch.github.io/blob/master/plugins.json)

Hope this clears things up a bit. If you encounter any issues, feel free to either comment there or open an issue on our GitHub http://github.com/brunch/brunch